# Set Rigidbody velocity in FixedUpdate() or Start()?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigidbody

I'm developing a simple 2D game in Unity (balls hitting bricks), so I have a ball and I want to fire the ball to hit bricks. Now, to fire the ball I have to set `velocity` on the `Rigidbody` component attached to the ball's `GameObject`.

There are two ways to do that:

**Method 1:**

*Set the velocity inside the Start() method*

```
private void Start()
{
    rb.velocity = direction * speed;
}
```

**Method 2:**

*Write a FixedUpdate() method and put the statement in there.* because:

> Use FixedUpdate when using Rigidbody. ([Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html))

```
private void Start()
{
    _setVelocity = true;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!_setVelocity) return;

    rb.velocity = direction * speed;
    rb.angularVelocity = 0;
    rb.gravityScale = 0;
    _setVelocity = false;
}
```

**But the thing is:** I don't need the `FixedUpdate()` method for anything else, because I only fire the ball once in its script's lifespan, so after I fire the ball Unity will continue to run the `FixedUpdate()` method and check for `_setVelocity`'s value and `return` (exit) every time because it will always be `false` after I shoot the ball the first time.

And this will happen every fixed time step which is expensive I guess for just setting the velocity only once.

**SO:**

1. Is it expensive to have a `FixedUpdate()` method that checks for `false` value and returns every frame?
2. Which of the two methods performs better in this case?

Comment: It sounds like you have your answer "I don't need the FixedUpdate() method...because I only fire the ball once in its script's lifespan". For a question about expense/performance, I'd usually say "profile it to find out for yourself" but in this case you don't need to: you *know* not calling a method every physics step is cheaper than calling it, so you don't even need to ask this question.

Comment: I know but Unity said in their Docs to always use FixedUpdate() when dealing with RigidBodies. So that's why i'm asking. [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Put physics effects in `FixedUpdate`" is talking about *ongoing* effects, not initial setup.

So really, it could be better phrased as "Use `FixedUpdate` *instead of `Update`* for ongoing physics effects"

Just put the initial velocity assignment in `Start`. Test your game. Observe that nothing bad happens.

Note that this caveat also means it's OK to put *instantaneous* effects - like responding to a jump button being pressed - in `Update`. It won't have an impact on the integrated position of the object until the next physics step (unless you're using extrapolation), but that's no worse than queuing-up the input and handling it in the next `FixedUpdate` anyway.